# Jest mocked MobX store not resetting between tests

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mobx

I have a simple login component and a MobX store which is supposed to hold some user information. I want to test this integration with Jest. The app is created with Create React App, so I am just building off that for my tests.

My Login component looks like this:

```
const Login = () => {
    const { accountStore, userStore } = useStores();
    const { user } = userStore;
    return(
        <>
            {user ? 
                <>
                    <h1>{user.fullName}</h1> 
                    <h2>{user.username}</h2>
                </>
                :
                <main className="form-signin">
                    <Button onClick={accountStore.RedirectToFeide} aria-label='sign-in-with-feide-button'>Sign in with Feide</Button>
                    <Button onClick={userStore.GetCurrentUser} aria-label='get-info-button'>Get Current User Info</Button>
                </main>
            }
        </>
    )
}

export default observer(Login);
```

My RootStore looks like this and provides the useStores hook:

```
export class RootStore {
    public userStore: UserStore;
    public accountStore: AccountStore;

    constructor() {
        this.userStore = new UserStore(this);
        this.accountStore = new AccountStore(this);
    }
}

const StoresContext = createContext(new RootStore());

export const useStores = () => useContext(StoresContext);
```

If the user in the store is present I would like to see their information. If not I would like to see the two buttons.

I have mocked the UserStore in a folder called __mocks__ like this:

```
class UserStore {
    private rootStore: RootStore;
    public user?: User;
    
    constructor (rootStore: RootStore) {
        makeAutoObservable(this)
        this.rootStore = rootStore;
    }

    @action
    GetCurrentUser = async () => {
        this.user = {
                username: 'username',
                fullName: 'Test User',
                dateOfBirth: new Date('1994-03-15'),
                email: 'test@example.com'
            }
    }
}

export default UserStore;
```

When I use jest.mock() in my test the GetCurrentUser method is mocked correctly, and the mocked data is set in the user object. However, I have not been able to reset the user object before doing a new test in any way.

I have tried:

- Mocking in beforeEach/afterEach
- jest.clearAllMocks(), jest.resetAllMocks() and jest.restoreAllMocks() both within beforeEach and without
- Adding and removing describes to isolate tests

The test looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { fireEvent, render } from '@testing-library/react';
import Login from './Login';

jest.mock('../../stores/UserStore')

beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
})

describe('User is logged in', () => {    
    test('Login shows users name after getting current user information', async () => {
        const { getByText } = render(<Login />);
    
        fireEvent.click(getByText('Get Current User Info'));
    
        expect(getByText('Test User')).toBeInTheDocument()
    })
})

describe('User not logged in', () => {
    test('Login should show sign in button', () => {
        const { getByText } = render(<Login />)
        expect(getByText('Sign in')).toBeInTheDocument();
    })
})
```

Since the first test presses the button and sets the user observable the second test fails. How can I reset the entire mocked store between each test?

Comment: Could you provide your imports in test?

Comment: I updated the question to include the imports in the test. @Eduardo

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue because I was using React Context without Provider.
After wrapping the main app with provider like:

```
const StoreContext = createContext<RootStore | undefined>(undefined);

export function RootStoreProvider({
    children,
    rootStore,
}: {
    children: ReactNode;
    rootStore: RootStore;
}) {
    return (
        <StoreContext.Provider value={root}>{children}</StoreContext.Provider>
    );
}

export const useStores = () => useContext(StoresContext);
```

I also modified `render` function from `@testing-library/react` to accept more arguments:

```
type CustomRenderTypes = RenderOptions & {rootStore?: RootStore;};

function customRender(
    ui: ReactElement,
    {rootStore, ...options}: CustomRenderTypes = {},
): RenderResult {
    const store = rootStore || new RootStore();
    return render(ui, {
        wrapper: ({ children }) => {
            return (
                <RootStoreProvider rootStore={store}>
                  {children}
                </RootStoreProvider>
            );
        },
        ...options,
    });
}
```

And after that every test case was getting the fresh copy of store and there was no need to reset mocks

Answer (score 0):

Try to include import of the hook you are mocking in your test-file.

**OR**

You can try to mock it another way: include import of `useStores` hook in the test. Then you call `jest.mock('useStores')`. And then you should mock its implementation.

```
import useStores from '../../stores/UserStore')
jest.mock('useStores')
useStores.mockImplementation(() => someDummyData)
```

Described solution you can find in [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules).

Comment: Importing the hook did not help, the other way you are suggesting gives me a typescript error: `Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type '() => RootStore'`. I was able to mock the stores using this: `jest.spyOn(stores, 'useStores').mockImplementation(() => new RootStore())`, but now my component is not picking up when the user observable changes.